# Looking for reference(s) about the Prophet Muhammad's (ﷺ) Dawah

Tags: hadith, seerah

I came across a [fatwa](https://www.islamweb.org/en/fatwa/193855/writing-islamic-pamphlets-and-distributing-them-to-non-muslims) that stated, "*the Prophet sallallaahu `alayhi wa sallam (may Allaah exalt his mention) used to visit people in their homes in order to call them to Allaah*." I am hoping someone can give me references to this, with how it is graded in authenticity.

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

Answer (score 4):

Please be aware that it is well known that the prophet() started his da'wah in a silent (private or hidden) way this may mean talking to people in their home before he started the "public" da'wah after revelation of

> Then declare what you are commanded and turn away from the polytheists.(94) Indeed, We are sufficient for you against the mockers.
> ([15:94-95](https://legacy.quran.com/15/94-95))

Therefore ibn Kathir (See for example [here](http://m.qtafsir.com/Surah-Al-Hijr/The-Command-to-proclaim-the-Tr---)):

> Abu 'Ubaydah reported that 'Abdullah bin Mas'ud said, "The Prophet was still practicing and preaching Islam secretly until this Ayah was revealed:
> ﴿ فَٱصۡدَعۡ بِمَا تُؤۡمَرُ ﴾
> (Therefore openly proclaim that which you are commanded) then he and his Companions came out into the open."

from this statement of ibn Mas'ud we can conclude that the da'wah was silent or in private before the revelation of this verse.

Another call for public da'wah was:

> And warn, [O Muhammad], your closest kindred.
> ([26:214](https://legacy.quran.com/26/214))

More details on the silent da'wah which toke three years are presented in the seerah books.

Here some relevant ahadith:

- In [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3522) (Chapter: The story of Zamzam).
- The following statement in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6865):

> ... The Prophet (ﷺ) also said to Al-Miqdad, "If a faithful believer conceals his faith (Islam) from the disbelievers, and then when he declares his Islam, you kill him, (you will be sinful). Remember that you were also concealing your faith (Islam) at Mecca before."

- In [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:832) (Chapter: How 'Amr bin 'Abasah became Muslim)

It also further well known that most of the gatherings happened in the house of al-Arqam. As @UmH mentioned, in the comment below, there's a story of da'wah narrated in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5657) where the prophet () visited a sick Jewish boy and invited him to convert to Islam and so did he() when Abu Talib was in his deathbed:

> Narrated Anas:
> A Jewish boy used to serve the Prophet (ﷺ) and became ill. The Prophet (ﷺ) went to pay him a visit and said to him, "Embrace Islam," and he did embrace Islam. Al-Musaiyab said: When Abu Talib was on his deathbed, the Prophet (ﷺ) visited him.

However in general visiting people at their home can mostly be concluded, as what we often find is that person X and Y accepted Islam in a certain occasion or situation.

You may also read something on this topic in [this article](https://islamstory.com/ar/artical/24267/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85%D8%A9-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%88%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D8%B1%D9%8A%D8%A9) -in Arabic-.

Comment: The prophet visited and gave dawah to the sick Jewish boy, presumably in his home. https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5657

Comment: @UmH thanks I don't recall this story. Where is it mentioned.

Comment: Added in the above comment.